# Play selected audio while pausing/resetting others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, audio

I have two audio elements that play through a button's click event. I've successfully managed to pause one if another is selected but also need to set the paused element back to 0.0 seconds (i.e pause and reset).

I'm aware that Javascript currently  doesn't have a `stop()` method which led assume that this would be done by setting its `currentTime` to `0`. If so I just haven't been able to figure out the best way to incorporate this method in my code.

Right now I'm pausing **all** audio elements in the latter half of the conditional using `$(".audio").trigger("pause");` which doesn't too efficient performance wise. What would be the best way to pause and reset only the  **previously played** audio file and not every one on the page?

**http://jsfiddle.net/txrcxfpy/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code . check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nishit_maheta/txrcxfpy/3/)

```
 $(function() {    
  $('.track-button').click(function() {
    var reSet = $('.track-button').not($(this)).siblings(".audio").get(0);
    reSet.pause();
    reSet.currentTime = 0;

    var $this          = $(this),
        trackNum       = $this.text(),
        currentAudio   = $this.siblings(".audio"),
        audioIsPaused  = currentAudio.get(0).paused;

    if (audioIsPaused) {
        currentAudio.get(0).play();
    } else {
        currentAudio.get(0).pause();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: you asked same question yesterday then delete . i have created demo of that . do you have yesterdays fiddle link ?? my demo also working

Comment: I quickly realized right after posting that I came up with a solution. This question more less deals with resetting the `currentTime` of the previously selected audio to `0`. The code you have now does pause the audio but doesn't reset the time. Also in your fiddle there's an extra `.` on line 3.

Comment: yes i will update and remove that `.` .  only thing remain is reset other audio to `0` right ?

Comment: Yes, thanks! Could I ask just one additional question. Out of curiosity I tried fading audio at the start and finish of a track. For some reason though it only  performs the volume increase/decrease on the very first click. Would you happen to know why? I didn't wanna tack onto my question but if needed I could update it or simply create another: http://jsfiddle.net/ge89g37o/

Comment: means i cant understand your question what you mean by `fading` ??

Comment: If you noticed in the fiddle the audio gradually goes from `0` to `100` and does that but in reverse near the end of the track. Does that make sense?

Comment: actuly problem is currently m my work place and all audio links are blocked . so not able to listen this audio .. i write above code yesterday night at my home :) .  can you add `currentAudio.currentTime = 0;` in side if condition above  `currentAudio.get(0).play();` . so it will start from 0 ?

Comment: every thing is blocked here . :) i only able to post comment and answer .. it possible when i reach home . around 9 indian time . sorry for that ..

Comment: No problem at all. I too will be remote for a while so possibly later. Going back to the original question though and speaking from a performance perspective, would it be wise to trigger the `pause` event on each and every audio element on the page? I'm thinking in a scenario where there are let's say 100 songs on the page. Referring to line 2 in the fiddle.

Comment: Also forgot to update the forked fiddle to show how the audio's volume animation: http://jsfiddle.net/ge89g37o/1/

Comment: its not here as audio not able to play . i will check and update you to night is it fine ?

Comment: That's perfectly fine with me. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked fiddle I have send you on chat??

Comment: No I never got the notification. Checking now.